# Laravel Firebase authentication error, unresolved dependancy

Tags: php, laravel, firebase-authentication

I started with this project: https://github.com/suhasrkms/laravel-with-firebase-auth (I downloaded the zip for email/password auth).  To duplicate issue I ran
`composer require kreait/laravel-firebase:^4.0 -W`
Updated from version kreait/laravel-firebase:^3.0 and I got this error.
**Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ string $projectId ]] in class Kreait\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient**

Originally I was trying to migrate this config to Laravel 10 with kreait/laravel-firebase:^5.1, however, for the life of me, I can't see how to resolve this error. I have the config file loading in .env, I can use my firestore controller just fine. I was hoping to quickly get front end authentication going, but this error is halting progress.
I'm guessing a config changed between version 3 and 4.

Comment: Just tried, installing new laravel (latest, in this moment v10) and requiring package of version 5.1 went with no issues.

Comment: Same.  But I try localhost/home and get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We must change the whole projects

```
use Kreait\Firebase\Auth;
```

and replace it with

```
use Kreait\Firebase\Contract\Auth;
```

And also the repository has been updated with the latest version refer [bump to Laravel V10.9.0](https://github.com/suhasrkms/laravel-with-firebase-auth/commit/035bc57dc0b5b6ecafe0c6ec5c1b637e76895c93).

Answer (score 1):

The kreait/laravel-firebase has updated the constructor.

LoginController.php

```
public function __construct(FirebaseAuth $auth) {
       $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
       $this->auth = $auth;
```

modify to this

```
public function __construct() {
       $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
       $this->auth = app('firebase.auth';
```